# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `ex25'

Tags: linux, bash, python

all

I have tried to make a program from 'learn python the hard way'. it's exercise 25. in the extra credit it tells me to go `help(ex25)`, but when I type that in, I get this on linux mint 15 terminal:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `ex25'
```

please help. this is my coding:

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """this function will break-up words for us"""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """sort the words"""
    return sorted(words)

def prints_first_word(words):
    """prints the first word after popping it"""
    word = words.pop (0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    """prints the last word after popping it off"""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """takes in a whole sentence and sorts it"""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """prints the first and last words of the sentence"""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    prints_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """first sorts the words, then prints them"""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    prints_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I quick read through that example at http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex25.html. Judging from your post, it sounds like you are typing `help(ex25)` at the bash prompt, while you should be typing that from within the python interpreter after doing the `import ex25` first.